# How to use segmented control as an add minus feature

Tags: ios, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to create an app where I want a user to be a able to increase and decrease a number using a segmented controller. I have two problems.

1. One side is always selected, how can I make it so it will only be selected when the user is touching it?

[image: The Plus side is selected]

2. How do I register if the same side is tapped? I have seen many examples where it shows how to register a tap on the other segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong control for this. There is a `UIStepper` which will do what you want.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistepper?changes=latest_minor